# como enviar un array php por json_encode y mostrar con datatables

Tags: php, mysql, json, datatables

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Necesito enviar algunos datos ya formateados o calculados en un array php a través de json para ser mostrados en datatables.

El tema es que he probado con varias posibles soluciones y ninguna muestra información al respecto.

Mi consulta PHP hacia MySQL:

```
$datos = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            $idventa = $row['idventa'];
            $mesa = $row['mesa'];
            $nombre = $row['nombre'];
            $apellido = $row['apellido'];
            $total = $row['total'];
            $fecha = $row['fecha'];
            $pago = $row['pago'];               

            $datos[] = array('idventa'=> $idventa, 'mesa'=> $mesa, 'nombre'=> $nombre, 'apellido'=> $apellido,
                                'total'=> $total, 'fecha'=> $fecha, 'pago'=> $pago);

            //$arreglo["data"][]= $data;
        }
        $array = json_encode($datos);
        echo json_encode($array);

    }
```

Donde recibo el json:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#listado').dataTable({
        "ajax": "list_reportes.php",

        "columns" : [{
            "sClass": "alignRight", 
            "data": "fecha",
            "render": function (data) {
                var dateString = new Date(data);
                return moment.utc(dateString).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            }
        },{
            "sClass": "alignRight", 
            "data" : "mesa",
        }
       .........
```

El porqué de hacerlo así, es porque necesito enviar algunas variables como `$total` que ya deben ir calculadas antes de ser enviadas y otras más que deben ser de la misma forma.

La consola muestra el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
```

Espero puedan orientarme con respecto a este tema, de antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los problemas que tienes son lo siguientes:

Un `Datatable` espera que se le devuelvan datos `JSON`, con [los siguientes parámetros](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) establecidos:

> - `draw (integer)`: El contador de `draw` al que responde este objeto. El parámetro `draw` enviado como parte de la solicitud de datos. Tenga en cuenta que **se recomienda encarecidamente, por razones de seguridad**, que establezca este parámetro en un número entero, en lugar de simplemente devolver al cliente lo que envió en el parámetro `draw`, para evitar ataques `Cross Site Scripting (XSS)`.
> - `recordsTotal (integer)`: Total de registros, antes del filtrado (*es decir, el número total de registros en la base de datos*)
> - `recordsFiltered (integer)`:   Total de registros después del filtrado (*es decir, el número total de registros después de aplicar el filtro, no solo el número de registros devueltos para esta página de datos)*.
> - `data (arra)`: Los datos que se mostrarán en la tabla. Esta es una matriz de objetos de origen de datos, uno para cada fila, que serán utilizados por DataTables. Tenga en cuenta que el nombre de este parámetro se puede cambiar utilizando la propiedad dataSrc de la opción ajax.
> - `error (string)`: **Opcional**: si se produce un error durante la ejecución de la secuencia de comandos de procesamiento del lado del servidor, puede informar al usuario de este error devolviendo el mensaje de error que se mostrará con este parámetro. No incluir si no hay error.

Por otro lado, solo para ahorrarte posible dolores de cabeza, deberías  [establecer los encabezados respectivos a una respuesta `JSON`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064468/3791844).

### Solución:

Aplicando lo mencionado anteriormente podrías modificar tu `PHP` de la siguiente forma:

```
$datos = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
  $idventa = $row['idventa'];
  $mesa = $row['mesa'];
  $nombre = $row['nombre'];
  $apellido = $row['apellido'];
  $total = $row['total'];
  $fecha = $row['fecha'];
  $pago = $row['pago'];

  $datos[] = array('idventa' => $idventa, 'mesa' => $mesa, 
    'nombre' => $nombre, 'apellido' => $apellido,
    'total' => $total, 'fecha' => $fecha, 'pago' => $pago);
}

$recordsFiltered = count($datos);

// NOTA:
// Por ejemplo, si la consulta esta paginada (eg: LIMIT 0,10)
// deberías hacer otra para obtener el valor para $recordsTotal
// En este caso, hago de cuenta que no se ha paginado
$recordsTotal = $recordsFiltered;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'draw'=> (int) $_REQUEST['draw'],
    'recordsFiltered'=> $recordsTotal,
    'recordsTotal'=> $recordsFiltered,
    'data'=> $datos,
));
```

Comment: adaptare mi codigo a lo que me propones. agradezco tu informacion. saludos